# What is that flutter error can you solve that?

Tags: flutter, android-widget

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAAm5.png)
This is my error - I can't solve it, please try to help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHYcq.png)

```
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:814:9: Error: The getter 'Srethrow' isn't defined for the class 'AssetBundleImageProvider'.
- 'AssetBundleImageProvider' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart').
image_provider.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Srethrow'.
        Srethrow;
        ^^^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:816:21: Error: Non-nullable variable 'buffer' must be assigned before it can be used.
      return decode(buffer);
                    ^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
Srethrow;
```

to

```
rethrow;
```